# How to compile C/C++ when installing a Python Package

Tags: python, c++, package, g++, python-packaging

So i'm trying to build a python package for my dissertation as a Comp-sci student, and the idea is quite similar to something like what [DIPY](https://dipy.org) does, but with multiple codes that other students from my university have developed during the past years. The thing is, some of these codes are written in C++, instead of Python. All of the C++ codes, have a python script running subprocess.call or subprocess.run to run the executable files, but i'd have to compile the .cpp files to even have a executable in the first place.

I've created some test packages with some of the codes developed in python, but my question is: How can i compile the codes written in C++ on the pip installation? The idea is that whenever someone installs the package from PyPI, this happens so that the user can just begin running the code afterwards.

How can i do it? Do i have any other alternatives?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, `setup.py` can contain any sort of python code, right? Even something heretical like `import subprocess; subprocess.run(["g++", ... ])`.

Comment: Thanks for answering! So if that was the case, i'd have to compile the .cpp files inside of the setup.py running subprocess.run and setting the output file as the default directory of said module containing the .cpp when installing it. Did i understand your idea correctly?

Comment: Also sorry @CaptainTrojan if i don't quite get it, but why is using subprocess.run heretical? Is it inefficient? Should i look for an alternative?

Comment: Yes, you understood me accurately! That's exactly what I meant, but I've never tried it - I only know how `setup.py` looks like. Also, I was joking when I called the idea heretical, I've just never seen this being implemented. I'm positive you'd find a few people here who would "nOt cONsIdER tHE ApPRoACh vERy pYtHOnIC"

Comment: Oh, i see. Well thank you for the idea tho, i'll give it a shot! :)